# How can I remote control my hardware Ubuntu desktop with spice, instead of vnc?

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, vnc, spice

I've used SPICE protocol on VMs, running on KVM/QEMU, but is it possible to remotely access my Ubuntu desktop session with a SPICE protocol, instead of VNC? SPICE performs a lot better, then VNC.

Comment: Ditto - can't believe it's so hard to find an answer for this... VNC is awful. NoMachine is awful, Teamviewer is awful... SPICE is actually good.

Comment: Yes, and I am still looking for an answer.