# Can I use SPICE as a VNC replacement for fast local 5ghz remote desktop?

Tags: networking, ssh, kvm-virtualization, vnc, spice

I know spice is used by virt-manager to control virtual machines. Can I use SPICE to do the same thing but over a fast 5ghz local network? I want to control the machine on the other room but I need it to be really fast, so VNC is out of question.

Reading the [spice downloads page](https://www.spice-space.org/download.html) there are lots of servers and clients, I'm lost. How can I make SPICE work like VNC? Can I also plug USB things in one computer and use them in another?

[How can I remote control my hardware Ubuntu desktop with spice, instead of vnc?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/953845/how-can-i-remote-control-my-hardware-ubuntu-desktop-with-spice-instead-of-vnc) has no answers

**UPDATE**: the intent is to use it with virtual machines in a server on the room

Comment: Please update your question with what you forgot to mention!

Comment: Do you already have the Virtual Machine setup? What did you use for that?
Adding images also may help.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonica I just installed virt-manager on the host and installed Windows 10 and Ubuntu virtual machines, nothing more

Comment: SPICE has unfortunately stagnated a bit the last few years. If you don't get very far with it, you might want to give [X2go](https://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/start) a look. This is very actively developed.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably ok for a comment, but being too long, I post it as an answer.

A long time ago, I recall dealing with a Spice server in Ubuntu.
I am now looking for a few sources that you may check.

This is one I remember reading
http://learn.linksprite.com/pcduino/desktop-visualization/install-spice-server-on-a-ubuntu-12-04-server-and-create-virtual-machine-to-be-used-with-pcduino3s-as-client/

These are others, with a varying degree of relevance. Some are related to Spice as a client.

https://hungpt7.github.io/en/note%20(1894).html

https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/SPICE

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/spice-protocol

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/spice

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/spice

https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_18.04&p=kvm&f=7

https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_16.04&p=kvm&f=10